# Using javascript to turn positive numbers green but only in certain table columns

Tags: javascript

This has been wracking my brain all morning, hopefully somebody can help me out here :)

Lets say my web page has the table included in the code below, the CSS & javascript are used to turn all negative values red. How would I go about adding to the code to turn the positive values green, but only in clolumn's 3 & 4? Id like the positive numbers in column's 1 & 2 to stay as they are.

Please note that the javascript is not my code, I know nothing about javascript as I mainly work in PHP, I found it when searching google.

I have tried altering the code and can get it to work if I precede the numbers with a + for all values, however the positive numbers are not to have a preceding +.

```js
function MakeNegative() {
  TDs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < TDs.length; i++) {
    var temp = TDs[i];
    if (temp.firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') == 0) temp.className = "negative";
  }
}
MakeNegative();
```

```css
td.negative {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center">Class 1</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">Class 2</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">Class 3</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">Class 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">Column 1</td>
    <td align="center">Column 2</td>
    <td align="center">Column 3</td>
    <td align="center">Column 4</td>
    <td align="center">Column 5</td>
    <td align="center">Column 6</td>
    <td align="center">Column 7</td>
    <td align="center">Column 8</td>
    <td align="center">Column 9</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>-87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>-87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not meant to write code for you. Learn JavaScript, try to solve this problem by yourself, and if you encounter any specific problem, ask here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550410/javascript-get-the-text-value-of-a-column-from-a-particular-row-of-an-html-table

Comment: first off all try to add a piece of css for the positive color. Then search for the spot where the JavaScript adds the .negative class. There you can try by yourself to add a piece of Javascript to make the positive values green. When you have tried that and it is not working we will see you around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work whenever you change size of columns or rows.

```js
function MakePosNeg() {
  TRs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  TDs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  var n = 0;
  var b = TDs.length / TRs.length - 1;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < TDs.length; i++) {
    if(n > b) n = 0;
    var temp = TDs[i];
    if (parseFloat(temp.firstChild.nodeValue) < 0) temp.className = "negative";
    
    if(n == 2 || n == 3){
     if (parseFloat(temp.firstChild.nodeValue) >= 0) temp.className = "positive";
    }
    n++;
  }
}
MakePosNeg();
```

```css
td.negative {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td.positive {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-70.6</td>
    <td>-99.2</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>-87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>87.1</td>
    <td>-99.2</td>
    <td>-99.2</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
    <td>-99.2</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>-87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
    <td>-99.2</td>
    <td>-99.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, please could you explain the code to me? How does it chose which columns to make the positive numbers green? Thanks

Comment: @LeePerkins Okay. _n_ is variable to determine if it's 3rd or 4th column. _b_ is number of columns. Inside loop, if active column is greater then max then we make it 0. If active column is 3 or 4 (in array it's 2 and 3) then we make it green. At the end of the loop we increment active column number. Ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: In this case we have 25 cells. So in array it has addresses from 0 to 24. It's why we check 2 and 3 (not 3 and 4).

Comment: thanks mate, appreciated!!! I also have another title row above the column row and the colspan/rowspan is throwing it out. I didn't include it in the original question because I didn't think it was relevant however I have updated it to reflect this. I am trying to figure it out myself however as mentioned I dont know javascript so I may run into a brick wall so to speak. If you are willing please could you point me in the direction of editing your code to reflect the new table structure?

Comment: @LeePerkins Could you paste here new html table structure?

Comment: I have updated the original question to reflect the new table structure. It doesn't paste correctly into the comments.

Comment: <table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center">Class 1</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">Class 2</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">Class 3</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">Class 4</td>
</tr>

Comment: <tr>
    <td align="center">Column 1</td>
    <td align="center">Column 2</td>
    <td align="center">Column 3</td>
    <td align="center">Column 4</td>
    <td align="center">Column 5</td>
    <td align="center">Column 6</td>
    <td align="center">Column 7</td>
    <td align="center">Column 8</td>
    <td align="center">Column 9</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>-87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>-87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: You could just start working with css classes

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet.

```js
function MakeNegative() {
  Trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 1; i < Trs.length; i++) {
    var temp = Trs[i];
    Tds = temp.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var j=0;j<Tds.length;j++){
      if (Tds[j].firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') == 0) Tds[j].className = "negative";
      if (Tds[j].firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') !== 0 && (((j+1)%3==0)||((j+1)%4==0))) Tds[j].className = "positive";
    }
  }
}
MakeNegative();
```

```css
td.negative {
  color: red;
}
td.positive {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>122.4</td>
    <td>-87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>70.6</td>
    <td>-122.4</td>
    <td>87.1</td>
    <td>99.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```