# get each table column value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have an html table and i want to get each column value using javascript code

`var librarianDataRow=$(this).closest('tr');
        var librarianName=librarianDataRow.find('td:eq(1)').text();`

but i need another way to do that , assuming that if i change the order of column i will git the same result in javascript , for example : here Im use  **td:eq(1)** but if i change the order of column in html it will git different column , i need more effective way , can anyone help me !?
i mean , i want to get **librarianName** even if i change there order to be lets say the thired column in row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript get the text value of a column from a particular row of an html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550410/javascript-get-the-text-value-of-a-column-from-a-particular-row-of-an-html-table)

Comment: no , i want another thing

Comment: add you HTML and expected output

Comment: i want to get librarianName even if i change there order to be lets say the thired column in row , i don't want to use td:eq(1)