# I am generating rows, columns and setting an id dynamically. I need to target the 3rd column on the second row in JS. How do I target it?

Tags: javascript

I am generating rows, columns and setting an id dynamically. I need to target the 3rd column on the second row in JS. How do I target it?

```js
//Creates 3 Columns inside the 3 rows
var columns = document.createElement("div");
columns.setAttribute('id', 'columns' + j);
```

```html
<div id="columns0" data-col="badge" class="col-md-4 slide-in-demo" style="left: 0%;">
  <img id="icon0" src="http://bc-net/_catalogs/masterpage/V6/img/svg/signIn.svg" style="width: 15%;">
  <h5 id="header0" class="font-weight-bold my-4">People's Soft</h5>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" id="button0" href="#">LEARN MORE</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript get the text value of a column from a particular row of an html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550410/javascript-get-the-text-value-of-a-column-from-a-particular-row-of-an-html-table)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I apologize here is the HTML code. 
`<div id="columns0" data-col="badge" class="col-md-4 slide-in-demo" style="left: 0%;">
<img id="icon0" src="http://bc-net/_catalogs/masterpage/V6/img/svg/signIn.svg" style="width: 15%;">
<h5 id="header0" class="font-weight-bold my-4">People's Soft</h5>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" id="button0" href="#">LEARN MORE</button>
</div>`

Comment: No need to apologize, [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: @JuanAngelogianopulos and add a bit more JS. The above does not help to visualize a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
// row and columns are 0 based, assuming we have 3 columns per row as stated in the image
// example: getTableElement(1,0) would target id="columns3"
function getTableElement(row, column){
    var targetId = row * 3 + column;
    return document.getElementById("columns" + targetId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JavierFromMadrid I will try that one!

Comment: Your code worked. Now I am facing another issue. I am trying to append a badge I created to those 2 columns (5 and 6). But I cannot get it to work. Can you help me on this?

Comment: `function getColElement(row, column){var targetId = row * 3 + column;
 return document.getElementById("columns"+ targetId);
}
function buildBadge() {
var badgeContainer = document.getElementById('services');
var counter = document.createElement('div');
counter.setAttribute('id', 'counter');
counter.classList.add('counter');
var counterText = document.createElement('p');
counterText.setAttribute('id', 'counterText');
badgeContainer.appendChild(counter);
counter.appendChild(counterText);
getColElement(1, 2);
getColElement(2, 0); } 
buildBadge();`